# Expected value of two random variables with same distribution

Tags: probability

Why is it true that if two random variables have the same distribution, they have the same expected value?

Answer (score 2):

From a given distribution, one performs an integral to get the expected value.  If you give the same distribution twice, you get the same result of the integral both times.

Let $f$ be the PDF of the random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$.  (We *can* be slightly [more general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case), but let's not.)  [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case) $\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \; x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.  Every time we evaluate this integral for the same $f$, we get the same expected value.

Comment: What's an example of dependent variables with the same distribution but different expectations?

Comment: @uniquesolution : It's early here and I haven't sufficiently coffeed, so I guarded against conflating equality of the marginal PDFs with exchange symmetry of the joint PDF.  But several sips later, that was overcautious.

Comment: @uniquesolution If two random variables have the same distribution, then their CDF are the same (Because basically every CDF of a random variable is determined by the distribution measure which is induced by the random variable itself. And "same distribution" means they have the same distribution measure. ). Therefore, with the reasoning in the post by copper above, any two random variables which have the same distribution, shall have the same expectation, which has nothing to do with dependence/independence between them.

Answer (score 1):

In general we have $EX = \int X dP$,  and a little
works shows that if we define the cumulative distribution function
$F_X(\alpha) = P \{ \omega | X(\omega) \le \alpha \}$ then we can write
$EX = \int t dF_X(t)$.

Suppose we have two random variables, say $X,Y$ and
that $F_X(\alpha) = F_Y (\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.

The last expression for expectation then shows that $EX = EY$.

Note that $X,Y$ need not be defined on the same probability space.

Comment: FYI, the formula $\int X dP_X$ is absurd. Use either $\int_\Omega X dP$ or, for some real-valued $X$, $\int_\mathbb Rx dP_X(x)$

Comment: @Did: There was no meaning to the $X$ subscript other than to distinguish it from the corresponding measure on $Y$. I am not sure I see the absurdity?

Comment: The notation $P_X$ is universally used to denote the measure image of $P$ by $X$, that is, the measure defined by $P_X(B)=P(X\in B)$, aka the distribution of $X$. Hence a measure on the image set instead of the source set. Hence the absurdity (now corrected, which is good).